Drag a page down to transform into a different page
I would like to have an effect that's similar to a certain effect in the Polarsteps app, where a user can drag down on a step to go back to the map view of a trip. As you drag that page down, it transforms into the new view. I'm pretty new to Flutter, but I'm guessing it's not actually a Draggable but rather some sort of dragging animation to move between screens. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to approach this? Unfortunately I don't think I can add a video of the animation.
I have tried messing around with a DraggableScrollableSheet, but that doesn't transform of course.

I dont know if I got the idea but this app has an option that is a list of points saved or visited and we can slide this list updating the map in the same time.
Would that be the idea?
